# Create a variable for a cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code :

```vb
If Sheets("CM").Cells(a, b).Value = "" Then
   Sheets("CM").Cells(a, b).Value = shouldBeValue
End If
```

And I want to refactor it to this one :

```vb
c = Sheets("CM").Cells(a, b)
If c.Value = "" Then
   c.Value = shouldBeValue
End If
```

But I get an error "Expected Object" at the If line, I don't understand why.

Comment: You have to put a `Set c = cell` if you want to do object assignment.  If you just do `c = cell` then it will assign only the cell's value (because `.Value` is the default property).

Comment: So what's the difference between creating a variable with "x =" compared to "Set x =" ? I'm new to VBA :)

Comment: Normal variables just have a value. Object variables have a value, other properties, methods, etc...

Comment: In there first case you are creating a variant variable that *contains a value*, in the 2nd case you are creating a variant variable that is *pointing to an object*.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Whether a variant variable *contains a value* depends on its current subtype. If its data is a string or an array or an object it is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

### Creating Object References

- [`Set statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

```vb
' To create references to objects you need to use the 'Set' keyword.

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Cells(a, b)

If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = 0 Then ' blank i.e. empty, ="", ', ...
'If IsEmpty(cell) Then ' empty
    cell.Value = shouldBeValue
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Object variables require the `Set` keyword to be used when assigning their target object:

```
Set c = Sheets("CM").Cells(a, b)
```

But you should also consider the advantages of an implicit object reference:

```
With Sheets("CM").Cells(a, b)
    If .Value = "" Then .Value = shouldBeValue
End With
```

Using the `With` statement allows the enclosed code to reference the specified object without further direct reference. In other words, implicitly. In this example, the code makes implicit reference to the `Cells(a, b)` object twice with `.Value`. This technique eliminates the need for a separate object variable; it makes the code easier to read and shorter and clearer; and it often executes more quickly than verbose object referencing.

`With` statements can be nested, but only one can be active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be aware that in the refactored form you are just copying the value of cell (a, b) onto a separate variable 'c', but cell (a, b) will not be affected at all.
While in the original form, you are putting the value of variable 'sholdBeValue' into cell (a, b) if the cell is empty.